# Adding annotate text to plot with as.Date x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've seen similar questions but the answers did not seem to help my graph. I have a plot here:

```
n_cases_plot <- ggplot(data = n_cases, aes(x = month, y = n_cases, color 
= "#668cff", fill = "#668cff")) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
ggtitle("Number of Parole Cases Heard by Month") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.4)) +
guides(fill=FALSE) +
guides(color = FALSE) +
xlab("") +
ylab("") +
theme(text=element_text(size=12,  family="Georgia")) +
geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, aes(color = "lightskyblue1")) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "moccasin")) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

I'm trying to add text to describe the decrease as -29%. I've tried adding

```
 + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 10, "-29%")
```

But I keep getting the error

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Comment: Can you please include your data (ideally a minimal subset of your data) using `dput` so we can try to figure out the problem?

Comment: I think you need to use named arguments for the label (ie.  `label = "-29%'`). Otherwise, I think it might put `"-29%"` into the `xmin` argument

Comment: At what x value do you want the annotation to appear? `4` is pretty meaningless when it comes to dates... do you want it on the 4th bar? The 4th day? 4th month or year? You could try, e.g., `+ annotate("text", x = as.Date("2017-07-01"), y = 10, "-29%")` to stick it in the middle. If you address this and add the `label = ` as divibisan suggests, I think that will work.